# Pgfplots y label style in grouplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

For some reason, groupplot y labels seem to be very reluctant to styling. How can I

- rotate the ylabels,
- shift them a little bit closer to the tick labels, and
- have a multi-line label

in the following example? 
I have tried what feels like a 1,000 different ways of specifying the y label style, and none worked.

In particular, the following MWE does *not* work and yields this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=8cm,
    height=3.5cm,
    xlabel={Time (s)},
    xmin=0, xmax=7,
    tickpos=left
]
\nextgroupplot[ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, ylabel={$\sin(x)$}, y label/.style={rotate=-90, xshift=.5cm}]
\addplot[domain=0:7] {sin(deg(x))};
\nextgroupplot[ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, ylabel={$\cos(x)$}]
\addplot[domain=0:7] {cos(deg(x))};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `every axis y label/.style={rotate=-90, xshift=.5cm}` instead (and adjust the parameters to your needs). To have multiline, use e.g. `align=center`.

Comment: @marmot Hah, now I feel stupid. What do I need the "every axis" part for, exactly? If I have a normal axis environment, I can also do this without it, can't I?
And, uhh - should I delete the question?

Comment: I do not think it is a stupid question. I leave the decision whether or not to delete it up to you. `every axis` seems to suggest it applies to every axis but the effect is local, and it is used e.g. on p. 246 of the manual. At least from what I see it seems to behave like a local option if passed to an `axis`, but you could insert it globally with `\pgfplotsset`, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that works, I think. (I didn't find `y label/.style` in the manual, so it might mean it doesn't exist and thus does not have an impact. If you use `every axis y label/.style` inside the argument of an axis or a group plot, its effect will still be local.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=8cm,
    height=3.5cm,
    xlabel={Time (s)},
    xmin=0, xmax=7,
    tickpos=left
]
\nextgroupplot[ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, ylabel={$\sin(x)$\\ don't despair!}, 
 every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=-90,anchor=center,align=center
        }]
\addplot[domain=0:7] {sin(deg(x))};
\nextgroupplot[ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, ylabel={$\cos(x)$}]
\addplot[domain=0:7] {cos(deg(x))};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]